# Sbt downloads the dependency but IntelliJ cannot resolve its usages

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

#### The Problem:

I'm very new to Scala (but familiar with Java). I wanted to clone a [Sbt project](https://github.com/plofgren/fast-ppr-scala) and after several build refreshes it finally seemed to sync but  when I opened one of project files it showed `Cannot resolve symbol cassovary` ([Cassovary](https://github.com/twitter/cassovary) is a library by Twitter). I checked IDEA external dependencies and to my surprise it was downloaded by only its `META-INF` was showing **and when I checked the local ".ivy2" folder the bytecode and source files were there!**

It's interesting that all of the library's dependencies are resolved and IDEA loads them correctly. Only the main dependency has this problem.
[image: Cassovary not loaded correctly]
Cassovary library not loaded but it's dependencies are

Sbt version: 1.2.1

 IDEA version: 20.18.3.2 Community Edition

#### What I've tried:

Invalidate cache/Restart, different versions, manually deleting .ivy2 folder and re-downloading the dependencies, checking library issues in Github

---

#### build.sbt file

```
name := "fast-ppr"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

//resolvers ++= Seq(
//  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
//  "Twitter Maven" at "https://maven.twttr.com"
//)

libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" %% "cassovary" % "4.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"
```

---

[image]

Comment: You have installed scala plugin for intelliJ?

Comment: @Saurabh Yep. I used its bundled sbt

Answer (score 0):

Want to provide few actions that usually help me with such Idea problems:

1. Try to run SBT command in console before importing build to Idea (remove .idea folder before if it was already created). At my current project we even have such step in our FAQ for newcomers
2. Try to set SBT as default build option for Idea (screenshot below). It drastically decreased amount of strange compilation problems for me.

Sbt build option from settings:

[image: Sbt build option from settings]

Update:
Seems https://github.com/plofgren/fast-ppr-scala was originally built using Scala 2.10, and cassovary 3.2.0 available only for 2.10.

Please try to set scalaVersion := "2.10.7" and leave original version of cassovary  in build.sbt. Library API was changed in 4.0.0 comparing to 3.2.0, so without changes in the code it can't compile. And that`s why you get errors.

Then you can run "sbt clean reload compile" from console, to check if it works.

AFAIK cassovary support 2.11 since 4.0.0, so to run with more recent version of library you need to update code.

Comment: Seems like library API was changed in 4.0.0 comparing to original version from build.sbt. DirectedGraph takes type parameter, and current code just can't compile (FastPPR.scala).

Comment: Running with scalaVersion := "2.10.7" and original cassovary version set in build.sbt works fine for me. For using more recent version of this lib you need update code.